# Resending an email to a list of address in the Bcc

Tags: gmail

I sent an email to several addresses, that I put in the "Bcc" field. Now I want to send another email to the same addresses. How can I do this? I tried "reply", but it replies only to me—I didn't find a "reply all" option. I tried copying&pasting but got strange errors about "unidentified addresses".

Comment: Yeah it's annoying that the reply/reply all buttons are useless if your recipients are in the BCC. It would be great if some extension could correct this behavior as copy-pasting is tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you sent the email using a mail client (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc) then I believe you are out of luck as most of these strip out the BCC fields upon sending.  If you sent it from the Gmail site, then you can recover the addresses.

To do so, go to the Sent folder and select the message, then click the dropdown arrow in the **bcc:** field location.

[image]

The popout window this provides will include all the addresses in the BCC field.  You can copy these and then paste them into a new email to send to them again.  Because you are copying from a "display" field, not truly an email field, you may unintentionally include extra characters or non-email words (display names, etc).  When you paste into a new email, check to see which Gmail has recognized as true email addresses and remove or correct any that it is unable to recognize.  This should prevent any further "unidentified addresses" errors.

Answer (score 1):

For Gmail users, go to the original sent email in your sent folder. Click on the 3 dots on right for other options. Click "see original email" and then a full screen version will appear, with no changes in the BCC addresses. Copy and paste to your new composed email. 
I sure could have used this information myself-lol-lots of annoying time spent trying to edit the addresses until I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Open the original e mail. It will be in the Sent file.
Highlight the first name on the list.
While holding down the Shift Key, tap the Down Arrow until all names are highlighted.
Right click on the highlighted field.
Choose "Copy"
Create new e mail and paste list into bcc field.

Answer (score 0):

Using Thunderbird, highlight and open the orig mail; go to File, Save As and pick a name, save as TEXT on the drop down.  The mail and the BCC list will be available as an easy copy and paste for a new mail.  This is not possible from the Thunderbird mail screen...BCCs are not selectable as a group and I had 145....

Comment: Using Thunderbird is a workaround, I guess, but the question is about using Gmail, and this site is about web applications.

Answer (score 0):

In outlook.live.com (a.k.a Windows Live Mail):

- Now, in 2021, there is a Reply All option.
  There is an alternative workaround too:
- In the pane for the message that you sent, left-click on the horizontally-grouped-three-dots icon at the top right of the message pane.
- In the menu that pops up, left-click on 'Print'.
- In the new (print dialog) pane that pops up, Select and Copy the email addresses that you want.
- In the new messagethat you want to send  (or even elsewhere), Paste the copied addresses into the appropriate field.

Answer (score -1):

For iPhone, go into your iPhone settings, select Mail, and add your gmail account to Mail.

From Mail, go into your sent folder (not your inbox), find the message, ensure your bcc contacts are there (mine were), and you should get a "send again" option.  Worked for me!

Comment: As this site is _Web Applications_, it's kind of expected that solutions will use a web interface.

Comment: I landed here from a web search, and this answer helped me. +1

Answer (score -2):

If you have yahoo you can select the message and at the bottom there a reply, reply all and more. In the more tab press raw message then you can copy the receipients address and paste in new email and then your done.

Answer (score -3):

This was helpful but I was unable to highlight the addresses.
Here's how I did it. Open the email in your Sent File. Click on File. Click on Message Resend and Recall. Click on Resend This Message. You can add or delete addresses and change the message as needed. His Send.

Comment: That sounds like what you would do in Outlook. This question is about Gmail. There is no "File" menu. There is no "Message Resend and Recall".